# Is it possible to see why my queries are so slow just by seeing the execution plan

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying learn how to optimize SQL statements and I was wondering if it's possible to estimate what might be making my queries slow just by seeing the execution plan.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 382856
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: rf
         type: ref
possible_keys: rec_id
          key: rec_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: rs.id
         rows: 7
        Extra: Using index condition
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: f
         type: range
possible_keys: facet_name_and_value,rec_id
          key: facet_name_and_value
      key_len: 309
          ref: NULL
         rows: 382856
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: r
         type: ref
possible_keys: record_id
          key: record_id
      key_len: 9
          ref: sqlse_test_crescentbconflate.f.rec_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Just by looking at the execution plan I can see that I am using too many joins and the data is too big since SQL is using filesort, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not really possible to diagnose the performance issue from just the EXPLAIN output.

But the output does reveal that there's a view query that's returning (an estimated) 384,000 rows.  We can't tell if that's a stored view, or an inline view.  But we can see that that results from that query are being materialized into a table (MySQL calls it a "derived table"), and then the outer query is running against that. The overhead for that can be considerable.

What we can't tell if it's possible to get the same result without the view, to flatten the query. And if that's not possible, whether there are any predicates on the outer query that could be pushed down into the view.

A "Using filesort" isn't necessarily a bad thing. But that operation can become  expensive for really large sets. So we do want to avoid unnecessary sort operations. (What we can't tell from the EXPLAIN output is whether it would be possible to avoid those sort operations.)

And if the query uses a "covering index" then the query is satisfied from the index pages, without needing to lookup/visit pages in the underlying table, which means less work to do.

Also, make sure the predicates are in a form that enables effective use of an index. That means having conditions on bare columns, not wrapping the columns in functions. e.g.

We want to avoid writing a condition like this:

```
where DATE_FORMAT(t.dt,'%Y-%m') = '2016-01'
```

when the same thing can be expressed like this:

```
 where t.dt >= '2016-01-01' and t.dt < '2016-02-01'
```

With the former, MySQL has to evaluate the DATE_FORMAT function for every row in the table, and the compare the return from the function. With the latter form, MySQL could use a "range scan" operation on an index with `dt` as the leading column. A range scan operation has the potential to eliminate vast swaths of rows very efficiently, without actually needing to examine the rows.

---

To summarize, the biggest performance improvements would likely come from

- avoiding creating a derived table (no view definitions)
- pushing predicates into view definitions (where view definitions can't be avoided)
- avoiding unnecessary sort operations
- avoiding unnecessary joins
- writing predicates in a form that can make use of suitable indexes
- creating suitable indexes, covering indexes where appropriate

Comment: Just to note, this isn't an exhaustive list of everything. The suggestions here do survey quite a bit of ground in terms of performance of `SELECT` statements. But this answer doesn't touch on a lot of other performance tuning topics: e.g. sql results caching, the differences in the storage engines (MyISAM, InnoDB, et al.), and tuning the mysql instance itself (e.g. memory allocated to InnoDB buffer pool, et al.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the `extra` field in the execution plan, and then examine your query and your database schema to find ways to improve performance.

`using temporary` means a temporary table was used, which may slow down the query. Furthermore, temporary tables may end up being written to the disk (and not stored in RAM, which the server typically tries to do if it can) if they are too large.

> According the [MySQL 5.5 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html), here are some reasons
>   temporary tables are created:
>
> - Evaluation of UNION statements.
> - Evaluation of some views, such those that use the TEMPTABLE algorithm, UNION, or aggregation.
> - Evaluation of statements that contain an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or for which the ORDER BY or GROUP BY
>     contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join
>     queue.
> - Evaluation of DISTINCT combined with ORDER BY may require a temporary table.
> - For queries that use the SQL_SMALL_RESULT option, MySQL uses an in-memory temporary table, unless the query also contains elements
>     (described later) that require on-disk storage.
> - Evaluation of multiple-table UPDATE statements.
> - Evaluation of GROUP_CONCAT() or COUNT(DISTINCT) expressions.

Then there's `using filesort`, which means that a sort was performed which could not be done with existing indexes. This could be no big deal, but you should check what fields are being sorted on and where your indexes are and make sure you're not giving MySQL too much work to do.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the execution plan to see why your queries run slowly because you know how your schema works (what columns and indexes you have). But, we here on Stack Overflow can't possibly use just the execution plan to help you.

There's nothing inherently wrong with `filesort.` It happens to have an unfortunate name; it simply means that satisfying the query requires sorting the results of a subquery.  It doesn't necessarily mean the subquery's results have been placed in an actual file in a filesystem.

Try reading this fine tutorial. http://use-the-index-luke.com/

If you need help with a specific query, please ask another question. Include the following information:

1. The query.
2. The results of `EXPLAIN`
3. The definitions of the tables involved in the query, including indexes.

Pro tip:  `SELECT *` is harmful to performance in big queries with lots of joins.  In particular,

```
 SELECT *
   FROM gigantic_table
  ORDER BY column
  LIMIT 1
```

is an antipattern, because it slurps a huge amount of data, sorts it, and then discards all but one row of of the sorted result. Lots of data gets sloshed around in your server for a small result. That's wasteful, even if it is correct.  You can do this kind of thing more efficiently with

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM gigantic_table
  WHERE column = 
          (SELECT MAX(column) FROM gigantic_table)
```

The best efficiency will come if `column` is indexed.

I mention this because the first row of your `explain` makes it look like you're romping through a great many rows to find something.